# How frequently do Gibdos spawn from hives?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I'm sitting in front of a Gibdo Hive in front of the

> Lightning Temple,

and I'd like to know how efficiently I can farm Gibdo Bones. To make this calculation, I'd like to know how frequently the hive drops out Gibdos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing it, I found that a pair of Gibdos spawn every 20 real-life seconds.

Comment: I come to this question to accept my answer, and I get this message: "You can accept your own answer in 8 minutes"

Comment: Self-answers can be only accepted after 48 hours from when the question was posted (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)). It's to encourage other users to submit their own answers too

Comment: I know, it's just funny that I try to accept the answer such a small amount of time before the accept blocker is removed.